# EFI pxe network boot error

Tags: linux, efi, pxe, tftp

**Asking this on both [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/100188/efi-pxe-network-boot-error) and [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/92295/efi-pxe-network-boot-error).**

When attempting to network boot RHEL 5.4 on an old ia64 machine I get the following error :

[image]

So I've basically followed the tutorial here : http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/doc/suse/sles9/adminguide-sles9/ch04s03.html

DHCPD,TFTPD etc are already setup and working with standard x86 PXE clients.

I've unpacked the boot.img file into /tftpboot/ia64/ and passed the path to the elilo.efi file via DHCP with the filename ""; option.

Changing this filename generates a PXE file not found error (see below). So I assume that PXE has found the file...

[image]

The only thing wrong I can find in the logs is :

Jan  6 19:49:31 dhcphost in.tftpd[31379]: tftp: client does not accept options

Any ideas? I'm sure I hit a problem like this a few years ago but I can't remember the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question - However, you may have better luck on Serverfault, but I will do my best to help you here!

I messed around with DHCP/BootP/PXE a while ago. The easiest thing I can recommend you do is to set up a virtual machine and install [TftpD](http://tftpd32.jounin.net/) as you can configure it to be verbose and diagnose problems.

From that screen, it looks like as it says, it simply cannot find the file - try messing around with forward slashes in the name (at the start), and keeping it simple, for example try just elilo.efi in the path and place the file in the root tftp directory.

When it comes to diagnosing things like this, you really want to take it to basics and get complicated when you know it is working.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I'll update/reword the question in the morning (GMT) with more info etc

Comment: Stupid me - I missed the top line!... Will copy my answer to serverfault as well so it can be criticised by others pros there and get feedback!